# How To Take Date As An Input To Alexa?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am new in skills development so please pardon me if the question is silly :)
when user says "alexa, ask agecalculator to calculate my age ?" then alexa reply "what is your date of birth ?" and the user tell the date of birth in any format like " 12 November 1995", "November 12 1995"

How can i get this date in nodejs variable so that i can pass this to my api .

Any kind of help or advice acceptable :)
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `AMAZON.DATE` as datatype for your slot in which you would like to capture the date from your Alexa skill.

You can then pass the data from this slot to your node.js lambda code.

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html

Comment: Thanks i fount it in documentation also :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey i am also facing the same one after searching a lot i found very usefull code from github as well as from amazon site also let me share all this with you.

Intent are like this if you are taking date as input

```
Intents :
    {
      "intents": [
        {
          "intent": "AMAZON.CancelIntent"
        },
        {
          "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
        },
        {
          "intent": "AMAZON.PauseIntent"
        },
        {
          "intent": "AMAZON.ResumeIntent"
        },
        {
          "intent": "AMAZON.StopIntent"
        },
        {
          "slots": [
            {
              "name": "date",
              "type": "AMAZON.DATE"
            }
          ],
          "intent": "Ask"
        }
      ]
    }
```

And from nodejs side you need to do something like

```
var date = event.request.intent.slots.date.value;
```

Here are the reference links for more information :)

https://github.com/robm26/SkillsDataAccess

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html